# SQL Delete duplicate records and leave the rest

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables a and b. A have 5 records and B have same records as A but 7 rows. Thats is same values in 7 rows. I wants to delete only the first 5 records in B since the row number is matches with A. How to do this. please help me.

table :A

```
    col1    col2    col3    DuplicateCount
    1        2       n         1
    1        2       n         2
    1        2       n         3
    1        2       n         4
    2        2       m         1
    2        2       m         2
```

table b:

```
   col1 col2    col3    DuplicateCount
    1   2        n          1
    1   2        n          2
    1   2        n          3
    1   2        n          4
    1   2        n          5
    1   2        n          6
```

desired data should reside in table b is

```
col1 col2 col3 DuplicateCount

    1   2   n     5    
    1   2   n     6
```

which is nothing but the last 2 rows in the table b.

Comment: what do you mean by records and rows here? can you differentiate?

Comment: consider all records as ROWS.

Comment: can you post some example data and desired output.. the description os not clear..

Comment: In the table a, 3 columns col1, col2, col3. data in each rows as follows 1 2 n; 1 2 n ;1 2 n ;1 2 n ;2 2 m ;2 2 m; In table b, the data are 1 2 n ; 1 2 n ; 1 2 n ; 1 2 n ; 1 2 n ; 1 2 n ; Now I need the only last 2 rows should be present in the table b. That is first 4 rows in table b is matched with table a.

Comment: @Robinclave, instead of giving it like a comment edit your question and post the table data.

Comment: Do you want to know how to `Delete the first 5 records from a table` and solve this very specific case?  Or do you want to do something more generalised, with your data just being an example?  If it's the latter, we would need a more detailed explanation on how to determine exactly which records to delete.  (Your example has 6 identical rows in table b, but you want to keep the last 2, what rules determine that you want 2 duplicates rather than 6?)

Comment: Guys, sorry for that confusing.. I put an example over above and desired output also. Hope this make you very clear.

Comment: Guys, the last column in both the table is not in the table structure. i just added row_number() in the select query to make it differentiate the duplicate entries.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
delete from TableB 
WHERE Id IN 
(
    select b.id 
    from TableB b, TableA a 
    WHERE b.Id = a.ID
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx#ide-E) key word for deleting first five records

```
DELETE TOP (select * from TableA a,TableB b where a.col1=b.col1 AND a.col2=b.col2 AND
a.col3=b.col3) FROM  TableA
```

or

Note: The below is an example for deleting one or more records based on their IDs

```
DELETE From yourTable where ID in (2,3,4,5,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

I added id column to identify rows in table B, I am not sure how to delete only some of duplicate rows without id column:

```
declare @a table
(
    id int primary key,
    col1 int,
    col2 int,
    col3 varchar
)

declare @b table
(
    id int primary key,
    col1 int,
    col2 int,
    col3 varchar
)

insert into @a values (1,1,2,'n')
insert into @a values (2,1,2,'n')
insert into @a values (3,1,2,'n')
insert into @a values (4,1,2,'n')
insert into @a values (5,2,2,'n')
insert into @a values (6,2,2,'n')


insert into @b values (10,1,2,'n')
insert into @b values (20,1,2,'n')
insert into @b values (30,1,2,'n')
insert into @b values (40,1,2,'n')
insert into @b values (50,1,2,'n')
insert into @b values (60,1,2,'n')


delete from @b
where id in 
(
    (
        select t1.id from 
        (
            select 
                id, 
                cnt = count(*) over(partition by col1, col2, col3), 
                rn = row_number() over(partition by col1, col2, col3 order by id) 
            from @b
        ) t1
        join 
        (
            select 
                *, 
                cnt = count(*) over(partition by col1, col2, col3) 
            from @a
        ) t2 on 
            t1.cnt > 1 and t1.rn <= t2.cnt
    )
)

select * from @b
```

Comment: we cannot add a new column to that table. Can i use cursor to do this? any idea?

Comment: @Robinclave I can't tell about cursors since I have no recent experience using them. Here is an idea - create another table, let's say C, with all the columns from B and column ID as primary key identity. Insert all the data into table C from B, perform the query from my answer with C instead of B, delete all the records from the B and insert into B remaining records from C. The query actually needs ID column only in table B, it doesn't need it in table A.